# An example of outer measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

First a few definitions:

> 1.5.1: **Definition.** Suppose that $\mu$ is a nonnegative set function on domain $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^X$. A set $A$ is called $\mu$-measurable if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $A_\epsilon \in \mathcal{A}$ s.t: $$\mu^*(A\Delta A_\epsilon)<\epsilon$$, where $\mu^*$ is the outer measure of the measure $\mu$.

Now, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra of finite unions of intervals of $I$ with the usual length $\lambda$.

The the $\lambda$ measurability of $A$ is equivalent to the following:

for each $\epsilon >0 $ one can find a set $E$ that is a finite union of intervals and two sets $A_\epsilon^{'}$ and $A_\epsilon^{''}$ with:
$$A=(E\cup A_\epsilon^{'})\setminus A_\epsilon^{''} , \lambda^*(A_\epsilon^{'})\le \epsilon , \lambda^*(A_\epsilon^{''})\le \epsilon$$

I want to show this equivalence, $\Leftarrow$:

Assume the above last statement is true, then I need to show that there exists $A_\epsilon \in \mathcal{A}$ s.t $\lambda^*(A\Delta A_\epsilon)<\epsilon$.

So how to find the above $A_\epsilon$, I also need help with the other direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Your particular $\mathcal{A}$ here does not satisfy the condition $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^X$. But then, i don't see any reason for the existence of that condition either.

Comment: $2^X$ is the power set of $X$, this example is taken from Bogachev's volume 1 on page 17, example 1.5.2(ii); here's a link to the book: https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrnIrBxojNAhVrJsAKHQgqCWUQFggtMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdiendantoanhoc.net%2Findex.php%3Fapp%3Dcore%26module%3Dattach%26section%3Dattach%26attach_id%3D12514&usg=AFQjCNH9HvHhs6eP8JR-vwkuGiPvntKz1w&sig2=MZzOjp3IP47HlRgvxNs4QA

Comment: Ahh. I didn't think about that particular abuse of notation, though I have encountered it before. Properly, $2^X$ is the set of all functions from $X$ into a two element set - most particularly into $\{0, 1\}$, which only relates to the power set by the identification $f \iff f^{-1}(1)$

Comment: @PaulSinclair I know, but in this case it's $P(X)$, can you help me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is mostly caused by some misleading notation. It is $E$ that corresponds to $A_\epsilon$, not the two sets $A_\epsilon '$ or $A_\epsilon ''$.

$A_\epsilon '$ corresponds to $A\Delta A_\epsilon$, and $A_\epsilon ''$ to the difference between $\lambda$ and $\lambda^*$.

Comment: What? $A_\epsilon^{''}$ is a set and $\lambda ,\lambda^*$ are the measure and outer measure here.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist - "Corresponds to" does not mean the same as "is equal to" or "is defined as" or however you were interpreting it. The only reason $A_\epsilon ''$ is there is because the definition of outer measure used here can neglect covering a portion of the set, provided that portion can be made negligible. $A_\epsilon ''$ is the neglected portion.

Comment: I still don't see what "corresponds to" means here; how do you show explicitly the equivalence here?

Comment: What it means is that I had hoped that merely pointing you in the right direction would be sufficient to prompt you into figuring out the details yourself. The problem is a straightforward application of the definition, except that the notation used to state it is highly misleading. You really should start with using $E$ as $A_\epsilon$ and see if you can figure out what I mean by the rest.